# Django: Unable to populate checkbox using MultipleChoiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, widget, multiplechoicefield

I am trying to save the choices(options) selected by the user in the database and populate(check/select) the same using the data saved in the database.

Model:

```
class ScheduledEvent(models.Model):

event_id            = models.IntegerField()
project_id          = models.ForeignKey(Project, db_column = 'project_id')
start_date          = models.DateTimeField(null = False, default = timezone.now)
end_date            = models.DateTimeField(null = False, default = timezone.now)
next_scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
include_week_day    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
include_month_day   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The remaining code:

```
weekdays=(('Mon',"Monday"),
        ('Tue','Tuesday'),
        ('Wed','Wednesday'),
        ('Thr','Thrusday'),
        ('Fri','Friday'),
        ('Sat','Saturday'),
        ('Sun','Sunday'))


class CheckBoxdays(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ScheduledEvent
    included_week_day = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=weekdays, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

The options are getting saved in the database but the choices(options) are not getting populated from the data stored in the database.

But the following code works correctly:

```
weekdays=(('1',"Monday"),
        ('2','Tuesday'),
        ('3','Wednesday'),
        ('4','Thrusday'),
        ('5','Friday'),
        ('6','Saturday'),
        ('7','Sunday'))

class CheckBoxdays(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ScheduledEvent
    include_week_day = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=weekdays, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

The options are populated when the first value in the choice tuple is be a single character.
Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: I was wondering why don't you specify the choices in your model instead.

Comment: @Wtower: I tried that too ,but got an error, while saving the options:

Select a valid choice. ['Wed', 'Thr', 'Fri'] is not one of the available choices.

Comment: Ah, yes, multiple choice, right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Model version of the MultipleChoiceFile to do what you want to do:

```
class CheckBoxdays(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ScheduledEvent
    include_week_day = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(choices=weekdays, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Model version of the MultipleChoiceField"?
Can you elaborate/explain this?

Comment: you have to use the ModelMultipleChoiceField class not the MultipleChoiceField.

Comment: I am getting this error: 'ModelMultipleChoiceField' object has no attribute 'iterator', when I am trying to initialize the form fields with the values saved in the database.

Comment: How do you do the initialization of the form?